# how can i get a new access token not the lastAccessToken Using (openid / AppAuth-iOS) library to login with google in swift app

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, oauth-2.0

```
@IBAction func googleLoginButtonTapped(_ sender: Any`) {

     let authorizationEndpoint : NSURL = NSURL(string: 
       "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth")!
                        let tokenEndpoint : NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token")!
    
                        let configuration = OIDServiceConfiguration(authorizationEndpoint: authorizationEndpoint as URL, tokenEndpoint: tokenEndpoint as URL)
    
                        let request  = OIDAuthorizationRequest.init(configuration: configuration, clientId: "970857005723-hgran64vnmn3avdqeanvl3eq4seteau7.apps.googleusercontent.com", scopes: [OIDScopeOpenID], redirectURL: URL(string: "com.googleusercontent.apps.970857005723-hgran64vnmn3avdqeanvl3eq4seteau7:/oauth2redirect/google")!, responseType: OIDResponseTypeCode, additionalParameters: nil)
    
 

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
      //appDelegate.currentAuthorizationFlow
      appDelegate.currentAuthorizationFlow = OIDAuthState.authState(byPresenting: request, presenting: self, callback: { (authState, error) in
       if((authState) != nil){
     print("Got authorization tokens. Access token: \(authState?.lastTokenResponse?.accessToken)")
}
```

---

### the problem is here when i hint login button and login/register with an email it is returning the last access_token that holding data of another emails in every login or even in register a new google account

and it should give me a new access token holding no data without giving me the last access_token that holding data of another emails

---

### print("Got authorization tokens. Access token: (authState?.lastTokenResponse?.accessToken)")

---

but i want to get a new access_token not the last one using lastTokenResponse?.accessToken and i don't know how can i access that

Comment: Use `URL` not `NSURL` and then you won't need the cast to URL

Comment: What does 'hinting login button' mean?

Comment: `OIDAuthorizationService.perform()`

Comment: can you show it by code because it gave me invalid code when I write it @ElTomato

Comment: @Paulw11 it think that's not the problem now but ok ^^ I've edited it in my code already

Comment: Yeah, that isn't the problem,  just a style issue that cleans up your code.